# How to convert below nested json into pandas dataframe columns. Each node to a different column

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have below json sample, I want it to be converted to pandas dataframe. This is instagram data.
I tried few approaches but I am not getting all nodes as pandas columns.

```
[
{
    "dimensions": {
        "height": 734,
        "width": 640
    },
    "display_url": "someurl1",
    "edge_liked_by": {
        "count": 3797
    },
    "edge_media_preview_like": {
        "count": 3797
    },
    "edge_media_to_caption": {
        "edges": [
            {
                "node": {
                    "text": "some text1"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "edge_media_to_comment": {
        "count": 52
    },
    "id": "183471293",
    "is_video": true,
    "location": null,
    "owner": {
        "id": "191968"
    },
    "shortcode": "Bl2Nb",
    "tags": [
        "tag1",
        "tag2"
    ],
    "taken_at_timestamp": 153293,
    "thumbnail_resources": [
        {
            "config_height": 150,
            "config_width": 150,
            "src": "3382263118984904704_n.jpg"
        },
        {
            "config_height": 240,
            "config_width": 240,
            "src": "904704_n.jpg"
        },
        {
            "config_height": 320,
            "config_width": 320,
            "src": "904704_n.jpg"
        },
        {
            "config_height": 480,
            "config_width": 480,
            "src": "904704_n.jpg"
        },
        {
            "config_height": 640,
            "config_width": 640,
            "src": "904704_n.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "thumbnail_src": "904704_n.jpg",
    "urls": [
        "08864_n.mp4"
    ],
    "video_view_count": 0
}
]
```

I want it to be converted to pandas dataframe columns. e.g. I need "edge_media_to_caption>edges>node>**text**" as one column in my dataframe.
Please give me code or logic to do this in python 3.x.

I have tried following,

```
data = pd.read_json('file.json')

dimensions  display_url     edge_liked_by   edge_media_preview_like     edge_media_to_caption   edge_media_to_comment   id  is_video    location    owner   shortcode   tags    taken_at_timestamp  thumbnail_resources     thumbnail_src   urls    video_view_count
0   {'height': 734, 'width': 640}   someurl1    {'count': 3797}     {'count': 3797}     {'edges': [{'node': {'text': 'some text1'}}]}   {'count': 52}   183471293   True    NaN     {'id': '191968'}    Bl2Nb   [tag1, tag2]    153293  [{'config_height': 150, 'config_width': 150, '...   904704_n.jpg    [08864_n.mp4]   0
```

[image]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(data.edge_media_to_caption))
df1
[image]

Comment: Please include whatever code you have tried, so we can correct you or point you in another direction. While I could answer this, the goal of this site is to help stuck programmers, not write 100% of a solution for you.

Comment: Hi @DannyVarod: Updated the things which I have done.

Comment: Good start, some of the columns are plain values and some are json. You could reassign specific columns e.g. `data['edge_liked_by'] = data['edge_liked_by'].apply(lambda v: json.reads(v)['count'])`